# BadRequest when trying to get termsets from SharePoint Online termstore

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to get a list of terms out from a specific termset. But I get BadRequest and NotFound errors

When using this GET I get a BadRequest error:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/[siteID]/termStore/sets/](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%5BsiteID%5D/termStore/sets/)

If I add an the termset id after ...sets/[termsetID] I get a NotFound

When trying this [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/[siteID]/termStore/](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%5BsiteID%5D/termStore/) I get the correct termstore ID.

Can anyone tell why I get the BadRequest error?

Answer (score 0):

A "BadRequest" error when trying to get termsets from SharePoint Online term store using the Microsoft Graph API or PnP PowerShell could be caused by various reasons.

You could ensure that your app registration in Azure AD has the necessary permissions to read term store data. The required permission is typically TermStore.Read.All or Sites.Read.All. Make sure your app has been granted the necessary permissions, and if not, consent to the required permissions.

Then check if the access token you are using to authenticate with Microsoft Graph is still valid. Access tokens have a limited lifespan, and if they expire, you need to obtain a new one.